"libsystemd-core-253.so cannot open shared object file" and kernel panic on boot after update to 24.04
My system is reporting the above on booting after using do-release-upgrade to upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04. Kernel version is 6.5.0-44.
I'm not able to get to a command line. I've tried recovery mode, and the other older kernels available, with no luck.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to remedy this?
Edit: I was on 23.10, not 22.04

@steeldriver you're right, I've corrected the title.

@guiverc I've edited the post, I was on 23.10. Thanks.

I fixed this.
I downloaded the ISO for 24.04 and put it on a USB drive using Startup Disk Creator, then booted from the USB drive, selecting 'try Ubuntu'.
Once booted, I opened a terminal, ran sudo, and mounted my primary partition:
mkdir /mnt/rescue
mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/rescue

Then I ran some commands to prepare a chroot environment:
cd /mnt/rescue
mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf etc/resolv.conf
mount -t proc proc proc
mount -t sysfs sys sys
mount -o bind /dev dev
mount -t devpts pts dev/pts

Then:
chroot /mnt/rescue

Once chrooted into my broken environment, I ran commands to continue the broken installation:
apt update
apt dist-upgrade
do-release-upgrade

It now boots.
References:

https://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/chroot-to-repair-system
https://superuser.com/questions/1633747/how-to-mount-run-from-a-linux-live-usb-in-order-to-chroot

